# How to align buttons side by side in scroll view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I just started using android studio.. I am trying to align ImageButtons inside a scroll view side by side, but i cannot put them side by side, neither can i resize them from the left side. How do i align them side by side?

I already tried the solution given in one of the answers: [Aligning TextView Side By Side Inside A ScrollView Inside a Linear Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148770/aligning-textview-side-by-side-inside-a-scrollview-inside-a-linear-layout) but it didn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StoryIndex">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/titlee"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/alami1" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                    android:layout_width="375dp"
                    android:layout_height="116dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/alami2" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                    android:layout_width="195dp"
                    android:layout_height="169dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/alami3" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want the Image buttons to be side by side, but they are in rows, on top of each other.. but it shows like the one in picture: 
[Image of the design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mMgC.png)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the orientation in LinearLayout from vertical to horizontal.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            //The question you mentioned can be obtained by using weightSum
            android:weightSum="15">

            //replace src ic_launcher_background by your drawable source.
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/titlee"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this and let me know. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="15">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonOne"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonTwo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonThree"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this if you still find any issue, let me know.

Comment: @AliAhmed Please mark it as correct Answer. You are welcomed.

Comment: I did, but i have less reputation so it doesn't show :)

Answer (score 0):

Show the Image buttons to be side by side, and in rows.

Change the orientation of `LinearLayout` from `vertical` to `horizontal`.

Please try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/titlee"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="116dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/stars_one"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="116dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/stars_one"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="116dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/stars_one"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The output of above code is like:

[image]